# PYODBC Connection Not Closing

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, oracle, odbc, pyodbc

I'm using `threading` to execute multiple SQL queries simultaneously. I first append the connections to a list called `connections` as such:

```
import pyodbc
connections = []
num_connnections = 100
for i in range(num_connections):
    connections.append(pyodbc.connect('connection_string'))
```

This works and so does threading multiple queries. However, if I run this process many times, I get the error

('HY000', '[HY000] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12519: TNS:no appropriate service handler found
(12519) (SQLDriverConnect); [HY000] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12519: TNS:no appropriate service handler found (12519)')

I'm fairly sure this is because the number of ODBC connections becomes too high. When I try closing them with

```
pyodbc.pooling = False
for i in connections:
    i.close()
    del i   
del connections
```

the list `connections` is deleted. However, it doesn't appear it closed any connections because the next time I run `pyodbc.connect('connection_string')` I immediately get the same error. Any ideas on what this could be?